No answer found for SearchWeatherUseCase(#1among the configured answers: () io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for
I am trying to implement unit testing for my App. I have a ViewModel that takes use-cases as parameters injected in the constructor below
@HiltViewModel
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val searchWeatherUseCase: SearchWeatherUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<WeatherUiState> =
        MutableStateFlow(WeatherUiState(isLoading = true))
    val uiState: StateFlow<WeatherUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()


    private val _searchWidgetState: MutableState<SearchWidgetState> =
        mutableStateOf(value = SearchWidgetState.CLOSED)
    val searchWidgetState: State<SearchWidgetState> = _searchWidgetState

    private val _searchTextState: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(value = "")
    val searchTextState: State<String> = _searchTextState

    fun updateSearchWidgetState(newValue: SearchWidgetState) {
        _searchWidgetState.value = newValue
    }

    fun updateSearchTextState(newValue: String) {
        _searchTextState.value = newValue
    }

    init {
        getWeather()
    }

    fun getWeather(city: String = DEFAULT_WEATHER_DESTINATION) {
        searchWeatherUseCase.getCities(city).map { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val apiData = result.data
                    val isFavorite = data.find { apiData.name == it.name }
                    _uiState.value = WeatherUiState(
                        weather = apiData,
               
                    )
                }

                is Result.Error -> {
                    _uiState.value = WeatherUiState(errorMessage = result.errorMessage)
                }

                Result.Loading -> {
                    _uiState.value = WeatherUiState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)

    }

the request is then passed on to the UseCase then
class SearchWeatherUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repositoryImpl: WeatherRepositoryImpl) {
    fun getCities(cityName: String): Flow<Result<Weather>> {
        return repositoryImpl.findCityWeather(cityName)
    }
}

which then passes the request to the Implementation class:
class WeatherRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteSource: RemoteSource,
    private val localSource: LocalSource,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
) : WeatherRepository {

    override fun findCityWeather(city: String): Flow<Result<Weather>> = flow {
        emit(Result.Loading)
        try {
            val result = remoteSource.findCityWeatherData(city)
            emit(Result.Success(result))
        } catch (exception: HttpException) {
            emit(Result.Error(exception.message.orEmpty()))
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            emit(Result.Error("Please check your network connection and try again!"))
        }
    }.flowOn(dispatcher)

    override suspend fun saveFavCity(favouriteCity: Weather) = localSource.saveCity(favouriteCity)

    override suspend fun getFavCities(): List<Weather> {
        return localSource.getSaveCities()
    }

    override suspend fun deleteFavCity(city: String) = localSource.deleteFavCity(city)

    override suspend fun fetchFavouriteWeatherByName(name: String): Weather =
        localSource.fetchFavouriteWeatherByName(name)


}

which decides whether the data must come from Remote or Local sources. In my case, it is Remote source, which is:
class RemoteSource @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiInterface) {

    suspend fun findCityWeatherData(city: String): Weather {
        return api.findCityWeatherData(q = city).toWeather()
    }
} 

This is the flow of how data is being transmitted/emitted. And below is my WeatherViewModelTest:
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class WeatherViewModelTest {

    // Rule to handle LiveData synchronization
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    // Use MockK to mock use cases
    private lateinit var searchWeatherUseCase: SearchWeatherUseCase
    private lateinit var saveCityUseCase: SaveCityUseCase
    private lateinit var getSaveCityUseCase: GetSaveCityUseCase
    private lateinit var deleteSaveCityUseCase: DeleteSaveCityUseCase
    private lateinit var getFavouriteCityUseCase: GetFavouriteCityUseCase

    // ViewModel under test
    private lateinit var weatherViewModel: WeatherViewModel

    // Test Dispatcher
    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // Mock the use cases
        searchWeatherUseCase = mockk()
        getSaveCityUseCase = mockk()
        saveCityUseCase = mockk()
        deleteSaveCityUseCase = mockk()

        // Initialize ViewModel with the mocked use cases
        weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel(
            searchWeatherUseCase,
            saveCityUseCase,
            getSaveCityUseCase,
            deleteSaveCityUseCase
        )

        // Set up common behavior for saving cities
        coEvery { getSaveCityUseCase.getSaveCities() } returns listOf(
            Weather(
                id = 1L,
                temperature = 25,
                date = "2023-09-25",
                wind = 10,
                humidity = 60,
                feelsLike = 24,
                uv = 5,
                name = "Cottbus",
                isFavourite = true
            )
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `getWeather() should update uiState with weather data when result is success`() = runTest {
        // Given a successful weather fetch result
        val weather = Weather(
            id = 1L,
            temperature = 25,
            date = "2023-09-25",
            wind = 10,
            humidity = 60,
            feelsLike = 24,
            uv = 5,
            name = "Cottbus",
            isFavourite = true
        )

        // Mock the behavior of searchWeatherUseCase.getCities for "Cottbus"
        coEvery { searchWeatherUseCase.getCities("Cottbus") } returns flowOf(Result.Success(weather))

        // When fetching weather for a city
        weatherViewModel.getWeather("Cottbus")

        // Run the pending coroutines
        advanceUntilIdle()

        // Verify that the getCities method was called with "Cottbus"
        coVerify { searchWeatherUseCase.getCities("Cottbus") }

        // Assert that the ViewModel updates the UI state correctly
        val expectedUiState = WeatherUiState(
            weather = weather,
            favouriteCity = listOf(weather),
            isFavorite = true
        )

        assertEquals(expectedUiState, weatherViewModel.uiState.value)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // Reset the dispatcher after the test
    }


    @Test
    fun `getWeather() should update uiState with error when result is failure`() = runTest {
        // Given a failure weather fetch result
        val errorMessage = "Network error"
        coEvery { searchWeatherUseCase.getCities(any()) } returns flowOf(Result.Error(errorMessage))

        // When fetching weather for a city
        weatherViewModel.getWeather("Test City")

        // Run the pending coroutines
        advanceUntilIdle()

        // Then assert that the UI state is updated with an error message
        assertEquals(errorMessage, weatherViewModel.uiState.value.errorMessage)
    }
}

The test is failing and is generating the error below:
no answer found for SearchWeatherUseCase(#1).getCities(Cottbus) among the configured answers: ()
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for SearchWeatherUseCase(#1).getCities(Cottbus) among the configured answers: ()
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:91)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:269)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:24)
    at app//io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.data.usecase.SearchWeatherUseCase.getCities(SearchWeatherUseCase.kt:11)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.getWeather(WeatherViewModel.kt:65)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.getWeather$default(WeatherViewModel.kt:64)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.<init>(WeatherViewModel.kt:60)
    at app//WeatherViewModelTest.setup(WeatherViewModelTest.kt:56)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at app//org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


no answer found for SearchWeatherUseCase(#5).getCities(Cottbus) among the configured answers: ()
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for SearchWeatherUseCase(#5).getCities(Cottbus) among the configured answers: ()
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:91)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:269)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:24)
    at app//io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.data.usecase.SearchWeatherUseCase.getCities(SearchWeatherUseCase.kt:11)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.getWeather(WeatherViewModel.kt:65)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.getWeather$default(WeatherViewModel.kt:64)
    at app//com.example.weatherviewer.ui.viewmodels.WeatherViewModel.<init>(WeatherViewModel.kt:60)
    at app//WeatherViewModelTest.setup(WeatherViewModelTest.kt:56)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at app//org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.11/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

